# How to store iframe in a variable?

Tags: javascript, iframe

```
<html>
<body>
   <iframe id="src">

</body>
</html>
```

I want to have the iframe show up in the div element through a Javascript function but I can't seem to figure out what isn't working. Any ideas?

```
document.getElementById('site').src = http://www.w3schools.com/;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't have an element with id `site`

Comment: Sorry for the type, but even if I do fix the id, it still won't show

Comment: On a side note, W3 Schools is awful, it contains ads all over the place and its tutorials are really low quality.  You should use the fantastic Mozilla Docs for reference instead: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try
`document.getElementById('src').src = 'http://www.w3schools.com/';`

a) the url should be provided as string (quoted)

b) the id of your iframe is `src` not `site`

Comment: Great solution, just one more question: I am using APIs that store all the url's in an array. When I try 'document.getElementById('src').src = 'thefeeds[i].link';', the code doesn't work. How would I fix this?

Comment: By removing the quotes. Your array stores the strings, so you want to use the value of that variable not the string representation of the variable you want to resolve.

Comment: Sorry to disturb you once again but by removing the quotes, the iframe is a blank page. I know the link is right because when I use the thefeeds.link in a href tag, it works perfectly.                                           document.getElementById("src").src = thefeeds[i].link

Comment: Figured it out! Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Your iframe don't have the id `site`, so your code won't have any effect.
(Also please note that you didn't close the `iframe` tag) .

Here's the right code ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HHxPU/)) .

```
<input type="button" onclick="changeIframeSrc('myFrame');" value="changeSrc">
<iframe src="http://www.example.com" id="myFrame"></iframe>

<script>
function changeIframeSrc(id) {
    e = document.getElementById(id);
    e.src = "http://www.wikipedia.com/";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, a couple small things:

1. the `id` on your `iframe` appears to be `src` and not `site`; and
2. you need to close the `iframe` tag.

Assuming that you're just dealing with one `iframe` and it has an `id` then by all means:

```
var myIframe = document.getElementById('src');
// gives you just that one iframe element
```

You may want to consider `document.querySelectorAll` though, in case you're working with more than one `iframe`.

```
var iframes = document.querySelectorAll('iframe');
```

See that in action: http://jsbin.com/equzey/2/edit

And important side note: if all you need is access to the `iframe` element (e.g., to manipulate its source or to apply CSS via the `style` attribute) then the above should be fine. However, if you need to work with the contents of the `iframe`, you'll need to get inside its web page context with the `contentWindow` property:

```
var iframes = document.querySelectorAll('iframe');
iframes[0].contentWindow;
```